# Check if number in range

Tags: google-sheets

How do I check if a number is in a range of numbers (not a range of cells). For example in many programming languages I can write `a >= 1 && a <= 7`. How do I express this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3):

IF(AND(logical_expression1, logical_expression2), value_if_true, value_if_false)

EDIT: IF(AND(a1 >=1, a1 <= 7),value_if_true, value_if_false)

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: What I am trying to discover is the syntax for a logical expression.

Comment: You could do it as I edited above, there is also a GTE() and LTE() function you could have used in place of the traditional >= and <=

Comment: There is a lot of information about logical expressions in Excel - they are no different than in Google Sheets.

Comment: My problem is where the expression is IF(AND(MATCH(a1,{...},0)>=1,MATCH(a1,{...},0)<=7),c1,c2) and MATCH is actually a very expensive computation, I do not want to duplicate it's invocation and I know of no way to save the MATCH result in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 3):

Use **ISBETWEEN()** function:

> ISBETWEEN function checks whether a provided number is between two
> other numbers either inclusively or exclusively.

Usage in your case (`a` === `A1` cell):

```
=ISBETWEEN(A1; 1; 7)
```

If `a` is in the range 1 - 7 it returns `TRUE`.
You can also set optional settings for inclusive/exclusive lower/upper value - by default is set to inclusive for both.

#### Parts of a ISBETWEEN function:

```
ISBETWEEN(value_to_compare, lower_value, upper_value, lower_value_is_inclusive, upper_value_is_inclusive)
```

| Part | Description |
| --- | --- |
| value_to_compare | The value to test as being between `lower_value` and `upper_value`. |
| lower_value | The lower boundary of the range of values that `value_to_compare` can fall within. |
| upper_value | The upper boundary of the range of values that `value_to_compare` can fall within. |
| lower_value_is_inclusive [optional] | Whether the range of values includes the `lower_value`. By default this is TRUE |
| upper_value_is_inclusive [optional] | Whether the range of values includes the `upper_value`. By default this is TRUE |

For more information see: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10538337?hl=en