# Check if number in range - Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula

How do I check if a number is in a range of numbers (not a range of cells). For example in many programming languages I can write a >= 1 && a <= 7. How do I express this in Google Sheets?

I tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100298/check-if-number-in-range/38100523#38100523?newreg=40bd5613d28b45608a19793acce14f64), but how would that formula work in order to handle multiple ranges?
For example:

C12 = 5

I want to check if C12 is either in ranges:

- 1-10
- 11-25
- 26-50

I'm trying the following but it's not working:

=IFS(AND(C12>=1,C12<=10),"1-10",(AND(C12>=11,C12<=25),"11-25","26-50"))

Comment: `=IFS(AND(C12>=1,C12<=10),"1-10",AND(C12>=11,C12<=25),"11-25",TRUE,"26-50")`

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :)
would you be so kind to explain the TRUE argument after the second AND function? I understand the formula will check if it's between 11-25, if it is, it will write that, if not, goes to TRUE, and then write "26-50". I'm just trying to understand what the TRUE is doing there. Is it similar to ELSE?

Comment: IFS expects pairs.  a boolean expression that resolves to TRUE/FALSE and the output if TRUE.  So with the last we need to force the TRUE.  It stops at the first TRUE, so if any of the others are true it will return them before getting to the last.

Answer (score 2):

IFS need pairs and it will short circuit at the first TRUE so we can shorten it to:

```
=IFS(C12<=10,"1-10",C12<=25,"11-25",TRUE,"26-50")
```

Or we can use CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(C12,{1,11,26}),"1-10","11-25","26-50")
```

Comment: Great approach ! ........................avoids the `AND()s`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=IF(AND(C12>=1,C12<=10),"1-10",IF(AND(C12>=11,C12<=25),"11-25",IF(AND(C12>=26,C12<=50),"26-50","NONE")))
```

[image]

same in Google-Sheets:

[image]